# .Net 5 Azure Pipeline - The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly' specified could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, webdeploy, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I upgraded our project to .NET 5 and get this error azure pipeline error when building:

```sh
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\agent\_work\91\s\src\Main.Blazor\Main.Blazor.csproj : error : C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\Sdk not found. Check that a recent enough .NET Core SDK is installed and/or increase the version specified in global.json.
```

The SDK `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly` specified could not be found

This is the task it fails on and .NET 5 has been installed on this machine, anything I could be missing?

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
   displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '842a57e5-e138-4563-9d88-36c4b1476f72'
```

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my comments under eduherminio's answer can help you and feel free to let me know~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there are 2 build servers and one of them did not get updated. The task:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 5.0.x'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: '5.0.x'
```

was not needed, once the other build server was updated the only other thing left was to update this task to use 5.x and set the CheckLatest to true

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x
    checkLatest: true
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error message, it seems that .NET Core 3.1.401 sdk is being used.

Try adding the following step before actually running any dotnet/nuget command:

```yaml
- task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET 5.0.x'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: '5.0.x'
```

Comment: I added that step before anything else and got this error:

The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found
The following frameworks were found:

3.1.1 at [C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
3.1.2 at [C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
3.1.3 at [C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.0 at [C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
5.0.1 at [C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Comment: It would appear that have a reference to `Microsoft.NETCore.App` in your project. Remove it, [it's not needed any more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).

Comment: @Danno The .NET Core 2.2 and .NET Core 5.0.x are not included in the Microsoft-hosted agent. As eduherminio's answer said, you need to use the [Use .NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) task to download a specific version of .NET Core. In addition, this task can specify the version of .NET Core to be used in the following tasks.

Comment: @Danno In other words, when you need to use .NET Core 2.1.0, add the task to download and specify it. When you need to use .NET Core 5.0.x, add the task again to download and specify it, just change the `version` parameter.